# How to check for NULL in a CASE statement along with numeric Types in PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to run below statement but it is giving me the below error

```
select
case SEA.CONTENT_RESPONSE_STATE_ID
       when null then C.DISPLAY_NAME
       when 58 then 'Task Submission'
       when 59 then 'Sender Approved'
end AS ACTION
from table sea join table1 c
```

I am getting following error

> ERROR: operator is not unique: numeric = boolean
> Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I am not getting where I need to add cast and why?

I tried adding cast as below

```
 when CONTENT_RESPONSE_STATE_ID is null::numeric then C.DISPLAY_NAME
```

but the result is not correct in case of null although C.DISPLAY_NAME is not null but action is still getting populated as NULL

Comment: case when SEA.CONTENT_RESPONSE_STATE_ID is null then C.DISPLAY_NAME when SEA.CONTENT_RESPONSE_STATE_ID = 58 then ... end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CASE variant you want to use can **only** use equality expression. Nothing else. In your case you want to mix equality conditions with an `IS NULL` check. In order to be able to do that, you need to use the more verbose CASE variant:

```
 case 
   when CONTENT_RESPONSE_STATE_ID is null then display_name
   when CONTENT_RESPONSE_STATE_ID = 58 then 'Task Submission'       
   when CONTENT_RESPONSE_STATE_ID = 59 then 'Sender Approved'   
 end
```

Comment: I tried this but forgot to remove CONTENT_RESPONSE_STATE_ID after case Keyword so was getting the error. Thanks for help